# Does someone remember a manga that has a sword with orbs in it?

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm trying to find a old manga where there is a sword wielded by a brown haired MC. I think I read it around 2008-2012 at a public library. If I remember correctly the MC was being hunted for being able to wield the sword, and he was running away through either a desert or rocky valley. The MC and sword are shown on the cover of the first volume if my memory is right.

Comment: Make sure your question title is useful: "Does someone remember ... ?" Yes, someone does. You do for example.

Comment: How did the sword have orbs in it?

Comment: Like are they embedded in the blade? The hilt? Floating around inside the sword? Was it magical, or more scientific where the embedded orbs cause the balance to shift as the sword is moved and/or that the orbs themselves are valuable (shades of diamonds hidden in hollow statues)?

Comment: The orbs were in the blade i do not remember if it was magical or scientific. And, I don't know if the orbs do shift or if it's the orbs that have value as i did not read much of it and it's been awhile.

Comment: In the blade? Like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLgJN.png

Comment: Have you contacted the library? 2012 is quite recent and they may still have the manga on display or recall which one it was

Comment: I'll see if i can check with the library directly but it wasn't on their website, and the sword isn't a traditional sword weird curves and stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is ***[Arata: The Legend](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/lbxadma/arata-kangatari)***.

> Every 30 years, a new princess is chosen from the Hime family to serve the Hayagami. The time has come again, but over these past years, records state not a single female has been born, save for one, the 15-year-old Arata. The only problem is, Arata is actually a male! Forced to disguise himself and take the place of the princess candidate until a formal one can be found, he attends the festival only to witness the current princess, Kokuri-hime, murdered, and his own life is forfeit as well, by the hands of the princess' personal guard, the 12 Shinshou. As he runs for his life, Kannagi of the 12 convinces everyone that Arata is the one who has murdered the princess instead, and now everyone in the Imperial Court is after his head! Now, another Arata from our world has crossed over in Arata's place! How did this happen, and how will these two survive?

Comment: And the sword with orbs; https://www.crunchyroll.com/imgsrv/display/thumbnail/480x720/catalog/crunchyroll/5b5985fdc8f385d4afd973c67cc1404e.jpe